# Easy way to quit a process in racket?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I find myself always getting tied up in an infinite loop in Racket. Often I'll mistype a variable or something and so a recursive process will just never end...and I'll wait a minute before Racket responds and I can click "OK" to quit it. Here's a simple example:

```
(define (fib-internal a b current-count total-count)
  (cond ((= 0 total-count) a)
        ((= b total-count) b) ; this is the offending line, should be (= current-count total-count)
        (else (fib-internal b (+ a b) (+ current-count 1) total-count))))

(fib-internal 0 1 1 7)
```

The point here is not to ask how to fix the above, it's that I make stupid errors like the above all the time and in the case of a mostly-recursive-language, infinite loops easily arise. Is there a better way to quickly quit a Racket process?

Comment: It sounds like you are using DrRacket. In it, there should be a "Stop" / "Kill" button at the top right, which does what you want.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase yea...but clicking it never does anything when I try.

Comment: @David542 It works reliably with your example in the latest DrRacket CS (version 8.0). A "harder" option is Ctrl-k ("Force the Program to Quit").

Comment: @David542: I can confirm this for Racket 8.0 on OSX: it stops pretty promptly when I press the big red button and comand-k (on Mac) also kills it pretty quickly.